# Can't add element to std::map using operator[]

Tags: c++, stdmap

So I stumbled upon a problem while programming.

In the code below, I'm trying to insert keys to `std::map<Cube, int> m` using the keys of `std::map<Cube, int> update`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct Cube {
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1;
    int y2;
    int z1;
    int z2;

    bool operator<(const Cube &o) const {
        return x1 < o.x1
            || x2 < o.x2
            || y1 < o.y1
            || y2 < o.y2
            || z1 < o.z1
            || z2 < o.z2;
    }
};

int main() {
    map<Cube, int> m, update;

    m[{10, 12, 10, 12, 10, 12}];
    m[{11, 12, 11, 12, 11, 12}];
    m[{11, 13, 11, 13, 11, 13}];

    update[{10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11}];
    update[{11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}];

    for (auto [c, _] : update) {
        // {10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11} is added to m but {11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11} isn't
        cout << m[c] << "\n";
    }
    for (auto [c, v] : m) {
        cout << c.x1 << " " << c.x2 << " " << c.y1 << " " << c.y2 << " " << c.z1 << " " << c.z2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
0
0
10 11 10 11 10 11
10 12 10 12 10 12
11 12 11 12 11 12
11 13 11 13 11 13
```

To me, it seems clear that I've accessed `operator[]` which should insert the key to the map.
I can't find any reason why `struct Cube {11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}` is not added to `m`.

I'm using gcc version 11.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) and compiling the program with `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -std=c++17`. I have also tried to run the code in an online C++ compiler, which gave the same results.

Comment: `operator<` doesn't fulfill the requirements for a map comparator so your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: The comparator of a map must induce a strict weak order. Your `operator<` does not.

Comment: When I need a comparator for a class and lexicographic ordering works just fine (what it appears you're trying to use), I use `std::tie` on the elements to make my life a little easier. https://godbolt.org/z/1efTK3TdT